# how to enable or disable scrolling on FlatList

Tags: android, react-native

I have a `FlatList` which is wrapped in a View.

```
<View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
<FlatList .../>
</View>
```

the View is a `panResponder`, so how to disable FlatList's scrolling when `onPanResponderGrant` triggers.

Answer (score 69):

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) states that a `FlatList` has the props of a `ScrollView`:

> and thus inherits it's props (as well as those of ScrollView)

If you check the [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollenabled) for `ScrollView`, you'll see that all you need to do is set the `scrollEnabled` prop to false to disable scrolling. How and where you choose to do this will be up to you since you didn't really post any code. A simple way to handle this would be to use state:

```
<FlatList
  ...
  scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
/>

// Change the state to the appropriate value in onPanResponderGrant:
// To enable:
this.setState({ scrollEnabled: true })
// To disable:
this.setState({ scrollEnabled: false })
```

Comment: I know this props, but it seems doesn't work, i will try again,thank u!

Comment: It works on the devices in my case, but not with expo web view.

Answer (score 3):

You can save ref to FlatList and call setNativeProps on this ref:

```
this.flatList.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: false })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <FlatList
      data={data}
      scrollEnabled={false} <---- use this 
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      renderItem={renderItem}
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -11):

Use ScrollView instead of View.

Comment: this can still be done by providing scrollEnabled prop in Flatlist